# Universal Application for IPhone/Ipod Touch 4th gen only + IPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, universal-binary

I'm developing a Universal Application that's only meant to be used on Retina display IPhone/IPod touch devices + IPad. How can I specify this on the plist or anywhere else in my app/binary?

`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` doesn't do the trick for both devices, since I could specify that I require `front-facing-camera` for the IPhone/IPod but that would exclude the IPad 1.

Comment: Why do you absolutely need the device to be retina display equipped?

Comment: It just doesn't look good enough on non retina displays. It's a game and we just don't want to deliver a sub optimal experience even though we will lose some buyers because of that.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible; as you are aware 4.0.x + is available for the 3GS/4/Pad etc, and whilst there is code that can detect whether a retina display is available or not, the option does not exist when uploading to iTunes. It's a no for now, I reckon.

Comment: yep, unfortunately it looks like it can't be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities should be used to restrict capabilities that your app/game really needs or excludes, it's not meant to be used to restrict a certain set of devices just because the developer doesn't want to support them. So basically you should always design keeping in mind all devices that are currently being updated to the last OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend doing this really, but you could just find out what device it is and then base loading your app on if the method `isCorrectDevice` returns true:

```
- (BOOL) isCorrectDevice
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine];
    free(machine);

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"] ||
        [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"] ||
        [platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"] ||
        [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"] ||
        [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"] ||
        [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"] ||
        [platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

There are a few problems doing this. One is, as soon as Apple release a new device this will be out of date and will not include the newer devices; but also, this won't stop users of other devices from downloading it. I guess you could just load a screen that says "Only available on..."? Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for this, but what we really wanted to avoid was users from downloading the app.

Comment: Yes I figured. Annoyingly this might be your only option. You could always produce a splash screen at the start saying "Optimized for the retina display" ;)

Comment: :) we are fixing it for 3GS, it was not as hard as expected, but it certainly doesn't look the way we want to.

Comment: I've found that devices the pre-date the 3GS don't run 4.0 very well and most users with that will be on 3.x! 3GS is definitely one to test with though!

Comment: we don't even have one! We borrowed one today and it's looking good so far, we are only supporting iOS 4.1, so older devices won't be a problem